# Mongoengine does manipulate image on storing

Tags: image, mongodb, python-imaging-library, mongoengine, gridfs

If i store an image by doc.image.put(rawimage) the image gets read by PIL and finally not the original one is written to the db, instad the output of PIL gets stored, which is a slightly modified one.

This makes it hard to run unittests to determine if the image has been written correctly by comparing md5sums.

Is there a way to bypass (didn't found one) this, or is this worth to file as a bug?